# In Jooq, how to fetch into LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I know that to fetch into `Map` I can use `fetchMap`, but it doesn't support `LinkedHashMap`, where I want to maintain the insertion order created by `orderBy`.

I tried

```
.
.
.
.orderBy(...)
.collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        record -> record.field1(), 
        record -> record.field2(), 
        LinkedHashMap.class));
```

but the `field1` and `field2` parts gave me the following error.

> Cannot resolve method 'field1' in 'T'

Hope someone can help me~

Thanks!

**Solution:**

Based on @Lukas' answer, I tried several times and found the following points must be done:

1. In the `select` method, all fields must have a type, except those calculated, where adding a type will throw `field not found in field list` error.
2. To add a type to a field, you have to use `DSL.field(fieldname, type)` method instead of `DSL.field(fieldname).cast(type)`. The latter will throw `field not found in field list` error.
3. In `collect` method's `collector` object, when getting each field of a record, they must have a type as well. Like

```
record -> record.get(DSL.field("fieldname", Float.class)),
```

The complete query will be something like:

```
Table<Record2<Long, Integer>> table1 = ...;
Table<Record2<Long, Integer>> table2 = ...;
.
.
.
return DSL.
        .select(table1.field("table1_field1", Long.class),
                DSL.ifnull(
                        table1.field("table1_field2", Float.class)
                                .div(table2.field("table2_field1", Float.class)),
                        0)
                        .as("result_table_field1"))
        .from(table1)
        .join(table2)
            .on(table1.field("table1_field1", Long.class)
                    .eq(table2.field("table2_field2", Long.class)))
        .orderBy(DSL.field("result_table_field1"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                record -> record.get(table1.field("table1_field1", Long.class)),
                record -> record.get(DSL.field("result_table_field1", Float.class)),
                (v1, v2) -> { throw new InvalidResultException("Duplicate key: " + v1); },
                LinkedHashMap::new
        ));
```

Comment: Why do you have to *declare* `LinkedHashMap` on your side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these approaches are assuming you're using the [jOOQ code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/)

#### `fetchMap()` already returns a `LinkedHashMap`

Check out the [`fetchMap()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchMap(org.jooq.Field,org.jooq.Field)) Javadoc. It says:

> The resulting map is iteration order preserving.

It's effectively a `LinkedHashMap`, though it doesn't guarantee this exact type, so you'd have to downcast at your own risk.

#### Using `collect()`

If you write a query that produces a `Record2` type, then you can use a type safe collector like this:

```java
LinkedHashMap<T1, T2> map =
ctx.select(T.COL1, T.COL2)
   .from(T)
   .orderBy(...)
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(
       Record2::value1,
       Record2::value2,
       (v1, v2) -> { throw new InvalidResultException("Duplicate key: " + v1); },
       LinkedHashMap::new
   ));
```

The reason your attempt didn't compile was:

1. You were missing the mandatory `mergeFunction` argument of `toMap()`
2. You should be using `value1()` and `value2()`, instead of `field1()`, `field2()`, but that only works if you have a type safe `Record2` in your result set
3. If you don't have `Record2`, but `Record` instead, then you can work without type safety:

```java
LinkedHashMap<T1, T2> map =
ctx.select(...)
   .from(T)
   .orderBy(...)
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(
       r -> r.get(T.COL1),
       r -> r.get(T.COL2),
       (v1, v2) -> { throw new InvalidResultException("Duplicate key: " + v1); },
       LinkedHashMap::new
   ));
```

Comment: I see. But if the method returns `LinkedHashMap`, there would be an error thrown, becasue the required type is `LinkedHashMap` while the provided type by `fetchMap` is `Map`. Should I simply cast the return result, like `return (LinkedHashMap<Long, Float>) DSL.select(...)...fetchMap(...)`?

Comment: @powerseed: Well, you can always downcast, but that might break in the (far) away future, when jOOQ's internals might decide there's a better order preserving map implementation than `LinkedHashMap`, or that the result should be wrapped in an unmodifiable map, etc. The concrete implementation type wasn't declared for a reason. See my updated answer for alternatives.

Comment: Hi Lukas~ I tried both the approaches but both gave me errors. The former throws `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context` at the `Record2::value1` and `Record2::value2` parts. My `select` is like `.select(table1.field("name1"), DSL.ifnull(table1.field("name2").div(table2.field("name3")), 0).as("name4"))`

Comment: The 2nd gave me the same wrong type error: the required type is `LinkedHashMap` but the provided is just `Map`. I will post screenshots of the errors in my question.

Comment: @powerseed: Well, you omitted your query in your original question, which is why I assumed you were using the code generator, like most jOOQ users. Why aren't you using the code generator? You won't get any type safety otherwise.

Comment: If you are referring to the `jooq-codegen-generate` task, I think I am using it. The version is 3.13.6

Comment: Do you mean in the `select` statement I have to use Pojos?

Comment: In the `select` statement, both the tables are `Table<Record2<Long, Integer>>`, not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: @powerseed you're not using generated code in your query, which leads to `Field<?>` wildcards getting in your way. Why aren't you using generated code? Please edit the question to add more details (i.e. the complete query). You left out the significant bits...

Comment: Entire query updated in the question. Please take a look. The current error is that the `collect` part throws `Unknown column 'engagement_score' in 'field list'`. The wrong type error has been solved by adding `cast()` at the end of each field.

Comment: Solved. Thank you so much for your help!